# Integrating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin x \cdot \cos^2 x \, dx$ by substitution

Tags: integration

How to find Integration.

$$\int _{ 0 }^{ \pi /2 }{ \sin x\cdot\cos^ 2 x } \,dx$$

**My work:** Let $\cos x =u$.

Upper Limit = $0$

Lower Limit = $1$

$$\int _{ 1 }^{ 0  }{ \sin(x)\cdot u^ 2 }  \,\frac{du}{-\sin x}$$

Can anyone help after this?

Comment: What happens when you cancel out the $\sin x$ on the top and bottom of the fraction

Comment: Hint:   $\cos (x)=u\implies du= d(\cos (x))=-sin(x)dx$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: with $$t=\cos(x)$$ we get $$dt=-\sin(x)dx$$
For $x=0$ we get $$t=\cos(0)=1$$
For $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$ we get $$t=\cos(\frac{\pi}{2})=0$$

Comment: I need help in substituting the intervals as I am getting wrong answer